# ASP.NET MVC3 and Facebook integration

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm just about to start a new ASP.NET project using MVC3, and since some of the requirements are about facebook integration, I need your advice on the following issues:

1- Is it achievable to connect my Membership users to thier Facebook accounts so whenever a user share/add/comment on an event on my website, I can automatically share these actions using his/her Facebook account?

2- also the ability to create Facebook events when the user create one on my site, and if he/she updates the event information, I may update them on Facebook too.

3- Can this be achieved using Facebook Connect, or this is only to authenticate users using their Facebook accounts?

4- How about using Graph API from my MVC solution, I know that there is a Facebook C# SDK on Codeplex http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com, but will it satisfy my mentioned needs or not.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've done something similar recently. Based on my experience:

1. Yes, you can connect your membership with a Facebook account, however it does not guarantee your user activity will be pushed to Facebook. (users have to log in with Facebook authentication)
2. Same as above. This blog post does a good job of describing it: http://amirrajan.net/Blog/asp-mvc-and-facebook-single-sign-on
3. No, facebook connect only takes care of authentication. For more information, check: http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/graph-api-javascript-base-facebook-connect-tutorial/
4. I have not tried the Facebook SDK you mentioned. However, I believe facebook Graph API already does a good job for you to and will fulfil your requirement