# C# MVC3 Facebook Integration, how to?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-c#-sdk

I have to provide my app with a good library for Facebook integration. For now, a FB login is all I need, but in the future I'll need more features.

With a quick search in Google I realized that the most popular library is http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/, however, I'm totally lost in how to make a login and get required information to my app. I followed the guidelines of [this link](http://www.bondigeek.com/blog/2011/09/19/facebook-login-integration/comment-page-1/#comment-945) but it doesn't make it really clear. In the Codeplex websites, the information seems to be out of date or missing some previous steps...

I also followed [this Stack Overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5412195/asp-net-mvc3-and-facebook-integration) that has a solution very similar to what I need and in a fast test, works. But I don't know if its the most elegant solution and the best for the future, when my app will have a lot of interaction, and not only login.

So, I'd like to know if someone can help me with:

1. A quick step-by-step guide on how to login with my Facebook account
2. A link with documentation to extend my app features, for example, how to post on Facebook programmatically.
3. My final question: using this SDK from Codeplex is really the best for my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the latest source code and checkout the "Samples" folder which demonstrates the usage of login and other various requests to facebook.

All your scenarios are in the samples. http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets

Comment: Thank you for you answer prabir. I was stuck with that. I still think they should improve their website with more tutorial, and remove the out of date posts.